# Instantiating all classes in directory

Tags: php, laravel, instantiation

I'm using Laravel and creating artisan commands but I need to register each one in start/artisan.php by calling

```
Artisan::add(new MyCommand);
```

How can I take all files in a directory (app/commands/*), and instantiate every one of them in an array ? I'd like to get something like (pseudocode) :

```
$my_commands = [new Command1, new Command2, new Command3];
foreach($my_commands as $command){
    Artisan::add($command);
}
```

Comment: with scandir('/path/to/dir')

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a way to auto-register artisan commands. (This code was adapted from the [Symfony Bundle auto-loader](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/master/Bundle/Bundle.php).)

```
function registerArtisanCommands($namespace = '', $path = 'app/commands')
{
    $finder = new \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
    $finder->files()->name('*Command.php')->in(base_path().'/'.$path);

    foreach ($finder as $file) {
        $ns = $namespace;
        if ($relativePath = $file->getRelativePath()) {
            $ns .= '\\'.strtr($relativePath, '/', '\\');
        }
        $class = $ns.'\\'.$file->getBasename('.php');

        $r = new \ReflectionClass($class);

        if ($r->isSubclassOf('Illuminate\\Console\\Command') && !$r->isAbstract() && !$r->getConstructor()->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()) {
            \Artisan::add($r->newInstance());
        }
    }
}

registerArtisanCommands();
```

If you put that in your `start/artisan.php` file, all commands found in `app/commands` will be automatically registered (assuming you follow Laravel's recommendations for command and file names). If you namespace your commands like I do, you can call the function like so:

```
registerArtisanCommands('App\\Commands');
```

(This does add a global function, and a better way to do this would probably be creating a package. But this works.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$contents = scandir('dir_path');
$files = array();
foreach($contents as $content) {
  if(substr($content,0,1 == '.') {
    continue;
  }
  $files[] =  'dir_path'.$content;
}
```

That reads the contents of a folder, itterates over it and saves the filename including path in the `$files` array. Hope this is what you're looking for

PS: Im not familiar with laravel or artisan. So if you have to use specific semantics(like camelCase) to register them, then please tell me so

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, but my problem isn't finding all the files in the '/commands' directory, rather find a way to instantiate all classes contained in those files then assign the instantiated object to a variable.